# Update TabView and move to Home View after login

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-environment

I have the fllowing TabViews in the ContentView. For the onAppear, it works fine. However, I am trying also to reload the tabs and move to the home after the user login from LoginView.

Following is the code of the ContentView

```
//  ContentView.swift
//  Matjri
//

//

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var user = User()

    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            if (user.tokenIsActive) {
                TabView {
                    HomeView()
                        .tabItem {
                            VStack {
                                Image(systemName: "house")
                                Text("Home")
                            }
                    }.tag(0)

                    UserPostsView()
                        .tabItem {
                            VStack {
                                Image(systemName: "person.fill")
                                Text("Me")
                            }
                    }.tag(1)

                    NewPostView()
                        .tabItem {
                            VStack {
                                Image(systemName: "plus")
                                Text("Add")
                            }
                    }.tag(2)
                    SearchView()
                        .tabItem {
                            VStack{
                                Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
                                Text("Search")
                            }
                    }.tag(3)
                }
            } else {
                TabView {
                    HomeView()
                        .tabItem {
                            VStack {
                                Image(systemName: "house")
                                Text("Home")
                            }
                    }.tag(0)

                    LoginView()
                        .tabItem {
                            VStack {
                                Image(systemName: "person.fill")
                                Text("Me")
                            }
                    }.tag(1)

                    SearchView()
                        .tabItem{
                            VStack{
                                Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
                                Text("Search")
                            }
                    }.tag(2)
                }
            }

        }
        .onAppear() {
            self.checkLoginValidity()
        }
    }

    func checkLoginValidity() {

        let userLogged = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "userIsLogged") as? Bool ?? false

        if (userLogged) {
            let existinLogin = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "loginExpiry") as! Date

            if (existinLogin > Date().addingTimeInterval(86400 * 2)){
                self.user.tokenIsActive = true

            } else {
                self.user.tokenIsActive = false
            }
        } else {
            self.user.tokenIsActive = false
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

When the user login from the LoginView, I set the tokenIsActive to true

```
struct LoginView: View {

    @ObservedObject var user = User()

    ........

    //Login successful

    self.user.tokenIsActive = true
```

TabView is not updating. How can I achieve this and I move the user to the homeview after login.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is used different `User()` instances in `ContentView` and `LoginView`. Here is a solution:

```
struct LoginView: View {

    @ObservedObject var user: User // << only declare
```

and here

```
LoginView(user: self.user) // << inject own user instance
    .tabItem {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "person.fill")
            Text("Me")
        }
}.tag(1)
```

Comment: Thank you. Now in the LoginView, I have an error for the Preview struct "Missing argument for parameter 'user' in call"

Comment: @Abdullah, yes, it should be done similarly as in my second code snapshot in all places where LoginView is used.

Comment: Sorry, the change has no effect. Maybe I am missing something. Shall I share the full code in next post reply?

Comment: @Abdullah, you can edit/update your question and add it there, or provide link, if any.

Comment: My mistake. After making this post, I was trying my post to sort it out and changed the code. Now it is working perfect. Thanks a lot.